# Python pyrebase updating values to Firebase

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> I have problem with updating value in database, I want only updating "counter" value not all array.
>   Here is my updating code, but i want only counter value update.

```
    with open('/home/pi/Documents/Raspberry32GB/config.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for i in data['config']:
        email=i['email']
        password=i['password']

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth= firebase.auth()
user=auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
useruid=user['localId']
db= firebase.database()
try:
    while True:
        datas=[]
        user=auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
        with open('/home/pi/Documents/Raspberry32GB/counter.json','r') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            for i in data['counters']:
                datas=json.dumps(i,indent=4)
                db.child("devices").child(useruid).child("counters").update(datas,user['idToken'])
        print(datas)
        #db.child("devices").child(useruid).child("counters").update(datas,user['idToken'])
        #db.child("devices").child(useruid).child("counters").update(dist,user['idToken'])
        #db.child("devices").child(useruid).child("counters").update(data,user['idToken'])
        #databas=db.child("devices").child(productKey).child("counters").get(user['idToken']).val()
        #print(databas)
except:
    print("Save Failed")
```

> Here is my database Structure, so I want only "counter value" update, but Error code is "Save Failed", by the way Error updating

```
  "devices" : {
"cIC0tFatD3XaYptUYWdZHQ0up8r1" : {
  "counters" : [ {
    "counter" : 19844,
    "countername" : "MainCounter",
    "flag" : 0,
    "maitenance" : 100000
  }, {
    "counter" : 630,
    "countername" : "Quicklock",
    "flag" : 0,
    "maitenance" : 650
  }, {
    "counter" : 144,
    "countername" : "Spring",
    "flag" : 0,
    "maitenance" : 2610
  }, {
    "counter" : 60,
    "countername" : "Linear Bushing",
    "flag" : 0,
    "maitenance" : 680
  } ]
}
```

}

Comment: Don't know about the issue here but you should be using google-cloud-firestore library to query your firebase data https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/

Comment: Thanks, but I use pyrebase libraray. I found documentation.